# Does SurveyMonkey support changing the positions of questions relative to an embedded image?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

I'm using SurveyMonkey to create my own surveys, and want to be able to position my multiple choice questions in line with an embedded image like the following:

[image]

am I able to re-position these? Or am I only able to change the positioning of these questions through making them horizontally or vertically aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the best way to do this, as custom CSS is not yet supported on SurveyMonkey, but a suggestion would be to [modify the question layout](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-change-the-question-size-label-space-etc).

This lets you specify the width percentage of the question (so you can set them side by side) and you can also set question spacing to align them better.

Also for each question choice there is a rich text editor. So you could insert an image for each choice, cutting the image yourself properly so that they align the way you want them to with your image. The question choices can also be multi-line so you could potentially pad the top/bottom with whitespace to make sure the image aligns.

I think with a bit of trial/error you can get this to work with those methods (not the nicest, but should work). Just note that if you're planning to have some people answer your survey in mobile it will likely not come out the way you expect it.